# asp.net core mvc connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, connection-string, always-encrypted

I'm using "always encrypted" on my azure sqlserver database, I'm using SqlParameter, .Net Framework 4.6 but when I use this connection string:

```
Data Source=name.database.windows.net;
Initial Catalog=My_Project;
Persist Security Info=True;UserID=MyId;
Pooling=False;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Column Encryption Setting=Enabled
```

I get the following error:  Keyword not supported: 'column encryption setting'.

Comment: Any chance of seeing the code that has this connection string? It seems find from here but it may be an typo in the code?!?

Comment: I'm new to .net core and I'm following a tutorial, the connect string works for accessing the database without "Column Encryption Setting=Enabled" but I need this to work with Always Encrypted for my azure sql database. My connection string is in protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder), I'm new to stackoverflow too so not sure how to post my code, sorry. My connection string has always been in the webconfig in previous projects so not sure if this is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems like you are using .Net core. 
Always Encrypted is currently not supported on .Net Core

You can find the list of supported frameworks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147923.aspx)

Adding Support for .NET core is on our roadmap, we do not have timeline for it yet